# How to add a Horizontal line above one sentence?

Tags: header-footer, ieeetran, line, ieeeconf

I am using the IEEE Conference Latex template.

I am trying to add a line above the sponsor section like shown in the image (sorry if it is a little bit blurry).

**The sponsor section is NOT a footer section**. it is generated using "thanks" command like shown in the code below:[image]

```
\title{Unnecessarily complicated title \fontsize{8}{8}\thanks{Identify applicable sponsor/s here. If no sponsors, delete this text box. (sponsors)}
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

To add a footnote rule you need to redefine it add to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\hspace{-1em}\rule{columnwidth}{0.5pt}}
```

However, be advised, the style file intentionally removes the rule with `\footrule{}`. Therefore, if you are sending something to an IEEE conference, you should keep the footnote without the rule.

Comment: It did not work properly. I need the line to cover the whole column width, not just above the words.

Comment: you control the length with the first brackets, the width with the second. If you want it to cover all remove the `0.95`

Comment: No luck unfortunately, I am looking how to insert the text inside a 1X1 table and remove all the borders, except the top one. As it was done in the MS Word template. if you know how to do this properly, I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Oh, you were talking about the left-hand side. I've changed my answer to accommodate that (using a simple `\hspace`). In LaTeX, tables work differently. You'd need to define a `tabular` environment and add an `\hline` at the top. This, in itself, is not hard. However, inserting the tabular environment into the `\thanks` command is not trivial. I wouldn't go down that path

Comment: I updated the image to make it more clear.

Comment: Can you describe in words the main difference between this updated answer and your image? I fail to see the difference

Comment: OK, played with the lengths a bit more. Again, this is completely tune-able. I fail to see where this does not solve the problem. If you want the rule to be a bit more to the left, change the `hspace` until you are happy. If you want to change the right side of the rule, change the length of the rule in `\rule{<length>}{<thickness>}`.

Comment: I posted the answer based on your suggestions. many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sport, I tried another way to go about this, as the OP suggested in his comment is to put the footnote in a tabular and have a single top line.

`tabular` environment does not play nice with `\thanks` therefore we need to use `savebox` in order to generate the table. This would look like this:

```
\newsavebox{\foo}
\savebox{\foo}{
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.4}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.94\columnwidth}}
 \hline\\
 Identify applicable funding agency here. If none, delete this.
 \end{tabular}}
 
\begin{document}

\title{Paper Title*\\
{\footnotesize \textsuperscript{*}Note: Sub-titles are not captured in Xplore and
should not be used}
\thanks{\usebox{\foo} }
}
```

Note the following in this solution:

1. We add `@{}` to make sure there is no column separation and in fact remove the extra in-table margin that would have been added.
2. We control the distance of the top line from the text using `\renewcommand{\arraystrech}{0.4}
3. The length of the table is controlled with the `p{}` definition. using `l` would result in the table "invading" the space between columns or even the right-hand column

This was not as complicated as I thought it would be but is certainly harder than my other solution.

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately, I updated the image to make what I want clear.

Comment: I posted the answer based on your suggestions. many thanks

Answer (score -1):

This line did the job.

```
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\hspace{-1em}\rule[0.45em]{\columnwidth}{0.45pt}}
```

it should be placed right before \begin{document}
and leave the "thanks" command as it is.